# How can I have multiple tableView functions in swift?

Tags: iphone, swift

I have 3 functions:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return fruits.count
}
```

and

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath ) {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Herp", sender: self)
    }

}
```

and

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FoodList", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            as UITableViewCell

        let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row] as Fruit
        cell.textLabel?.text = fruit.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = fruit.desc
        return cell
}
```

Is there a way to combine them into a single function instead of have 3 separate tableView functions?

Comment: Do you understand the concept of delegates or events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No these are `UITableViewDataSource/UITableViewDelegate` methods when you implement this protocol you have to specify the methods and the table view won't work without it.